# Enable validation for Hidden elements

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

Hi I want to validate hidden field value in MVC 5. Below is the view side code

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DecalLogoFileName, new { id = "hdImageName" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DecalLogoFileName)
```

I have many editor control for which validation is getting fire but any how this validation control is not getting fire on submit click

```
<img id="DecalLogo" name="DecalLogo" class="photo" ImageUrl="" />
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DecalLogoFileName, new { id = "hdImageName" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DecalLogoFileName)
<label for="imgInp" class="custom-file-upload">
<i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>Upload Logo
</label>
<input type='file' id="imgInp" name="image" />

<script type="text/javascript">
//Preview & Update an image before it is uploaded
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#DecalLogo').attr('src', e.target.result);
            $('#hdImageName').val(e.target.result);//Here I am filling my Hidden field control
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
$("#imgInp").change(function () {
    readURL(this);        
});
```

From above script code I am filling the value of hidden field control and I want to validate luike if this script is not fired then validation should get display.

How can I validate in MVC that on submit click that Image is upload or not.

Comment: Hidden inputs are not validated by default (although you can override that behavior). But displaying an error message associated with a value which you cannot see would be confusing. What is the property for and what validation attributes are applied to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically `jQuery validate` ignores `hidden fields`,`display:none` and any element with has invisible parent what you can do is override default behavior by applying

`$("#yourformid").data("validator").settings.ignore = "";`

**OR**

`$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: [] });`

> **This should not in** `document.ready`

Above line of code will validate all hidden fields in form which you have passed in some of the cases it's not quite good in some case you just want to validate only hidden field which has a particular class `XYZ` then do it like below

`$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: ':hidden:not(.XYZ)' });,`

Above line of code set a validator as a way to ignore all hiddenfields but validate hiddenfield whose class is `XYZ`

**UPDATE**

Validate Fields with particular `class` even if it's hidden.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.validator.setDefaults({
    ignore: ":hidden:not('.Validateclass')" // validate all hidden fields with specified class
  });
  $('form').valid();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <input class="Validateclass" name="hoge1" type="hidden" data-val-required="The field is required." data-val="true" required />
  <span data-valmsg-for="hoge1" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
  <input name="hoge2" type="hidden" data-val-required="The field is required." data-val="true" required/>
  <span data-valmsg-for="hoge2" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I had tried putting as <script type="text/javascript">
    $.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: ':hidden:not(.Validateclass)' }); </script>  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DecalLogoFileName, new { id = "hdImageName",@class="Validateclass" }) but is not validating

Comment: Currently the am validating by hidden field while writing model.isvalid on controller side, that mean page gets post back, but I want it to be validate before page gets post back, like other validation are working

Comment: okkk first check in console `$("#yourformid").valid()` what it returns ?

Comment: I had tried inserting this   $('#submitfilteration').click(function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var $form = $('form');
        if ($form.valid()) {
            alert("hi");
            //$(".loader").show();
            //$("#gotocontroller").click();
        }
        else {
            alert("hello");
        }
    }); and its is saying as valid. And it is validating the hidden nfield validation

Comment: It's returning `false` have a look [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bsq6e1b2/25/) you've done right thing where's the problem ?

Comment: Can You give me an example having 2 input hidden value and in that only one hidden input have class and i have to validate only that hidden input which have class. Please give this example in fiddle

Comment: I think instead of fiddle You should write fiddle code as your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160605/discussion-between-curiousdev-and-xtremcool).